# I shouldn't be able to vote to leave open after I voted to close

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

(This seems like something someone would have noted already, but a cursory search here did not find any such report.)

I had a tab open with the close review queue for a specific question. For whatever reason, I ended up opening the question itself in a new tab. I then voted to close the question from the new tab, not from the review queue. Then I went back to the tab with the review queue and I was able to vote to leave the question open.

In other words, I was able to vote to leave open a question after already voting to close it.

[image: Screenshot showing my close vote]

[image: Screenshot showing my leave open vote one minute later]

This seems like something that I shouldn't be able to do (at least without retracting my close vote). Indeed, if I refresh the tab with the review queue after I vote to close from a different tab, I *cannot* vote to leave open. Instead I get a message that the question is no longer reviewable. It also remains unreviewable even if I subsequently retract my close vote and refresh the tab again.

[image: Screenshot showing that the post is no longer reviewable]

[image: Screenshot showing that I have voted to close and retracted my close vote]

Comment: @WeareMonica. But it doesn't retract the close vote so it's not cutting out a middleman. It's just allowing me to vote contradictarily. And I just tested the reverse - I am still able to vote to close after voting to leave open.